# How to configure nginx to force download on a query param

Tags: nginx

So that `/media/file.jpg` opens in browser and `/media/file.jpg?dl=1` forces browser to download.

Here's my current config, that doesn't work:

```
location /media/ {
    autoindex off;
    root /home/my_app/media/;

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 365d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Allow forcing download by query param `dl`
    if ($arg_dl = "1") {  # why this doesn't work?
        add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement is never reached, because only the `location` is matched when a file is requested.

If the URL `/media/` is in `/home/my_app/media/` directory, you cannot use `root` like that. You need to either use `alias /home/my_app/media/` or `root /home/my_app/`.

You should try this (updated version):

```
location ~* ^/media/.+\.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    autoindex off;
    root /home/my_app/media/;

    expires 365d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    if ($arg_dl = "1") {
        add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
    }
}
```

Comment: nested location is not good idea, why not combing them into one?